# Positioning equation number not working

Tags: equations, numbering

In this example the equation number is even below the equation itself.
I thought a `[t]` of `[m/c]` option could position the number. Doesn't work.

How can I get the equation number to be at the top, centered, at the bottom?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\h}[1]{\widehat{\bm{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}[t]
\hspace{3cm} R(\alpha \h{a})    &\hspace{1cm}  \longmapsto  \hspace{1cm}  a.
\intertext{Note the special cases for the identity and the $\pi$-rotation:}
\mbox{Identity}    &\hspace{1cm}   \longmapsto     \hspace{1cm}  1         \equiv  -1 \\
\mbox{$L_a$}       &\hspace{1cm}    \longmapsto    \hspace{1cm}  a   \equiv  - a.
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\hspace{3cm} R(\alpha \h{a})    &\hspace{1cm}  \longmapsto  \hspace{1cm}  a.
\intertext{Note the special cases for the identity and the $\pi$-rotation:}
\mbox{Identity}    &\hspace{1cm}   \longmapsto     \hspace{1cm}  1         \equiv  -1 \\
\mbox{$L_a$}       &\hspace{1cm}    \longmapsto    \hspace{1cm}  a   \equiv  - a.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's the `\intertext`command that disrupts the equation number placement.

Comment: see here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33054/split-and-intertext

Comment: Do you want a number next to the first line and one cumulative number for the group after `\intertext`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution where everything is aligned, and one equation number for the whole set placed with any of the equation lines, or even with the intertext (emulated in the latter case with the `flalign` environment and the `\rlap` command):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry} %% just for demo
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\h}[1]{\widehat{\bm{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \hspace{3cm} R(\alpha \h{a}) &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} a.\\
\intertext{\rlap{Note the special cases for the identity and the $\pi$-rotation:}}
\mbox{Identity} &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} 1 \equiv -1\notag\\
  L_a &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} a \equiv - a. \notag
\end{align}


\begin{align}
  \hspace{3cm} R(\alpha \h{a}) &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} a. \notag\\
\intertext{\rlap{Note the special cases for the identity and the $\pi$-rotation:}}
\mbox{Identity} &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} 1 \equiv -1\\
  L_a &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} a \equiv - a. \notag
\end{align}

 \begin{align}
  \hspace{3cm} R(\alpha \h{a}) &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} a. \notag \\
\intertext{\rlap{Note the special cases for the identity and the $\pi$-rotation:}}
\mbox{Identity} &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} 1 \equiv -1 \notag \\
  L_a &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} a \equiv - a.
\end{align}

\begin{flalign}
  & & \hspace{3cm} R(\alpha \h{a}) &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} a. & & \notag\\[8pt]
 & \text{\rlap{Note the special cases for the identity and the $\pi$-rotation:}} \\[8pt]
 & & \mbox{Identity} &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} 1 \equiv -1 \notag\\
  & & L_a &\hspace{1cm} \longmapsto \hspace{1cm} a \equiv - a. \notag
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]